# A problem on statistic

Tags: statistics

If 10 or more defective product are found in quality checking, this batch of products are rejected. At least how many product must be checked to get a probability of 0.9 to reject a batch of products with a defective rate of 10%?

Comment: Someone posted exactly this question yesterday and I posted an answer to it.  Go to my profile and list my answers in chronological order.